# How do I bind a number and prevent scientific notation?

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to bind a number to an input box and make sure that it is never displayed in scientific notation.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right" 
       data-bind="value: myData, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

The input box should accept a decimal number of up to 8 places and I should be able to modify `myData` from my viewModel and have it shown as a number such as `.00000001`.  I'd like `myData` to be a number because I perform arithmetic on it within the viewModel.

The example [numeric extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) doesn't work for me because if you start trying to type `.00001`, it starts to update the value from underneath the user.  I've tried using ratelimiting, but that setting is finicky as it eventually changes the value from under the user as well.

Is there a way to code an extender such that the display binding to the input box is always `toFixed(8)` while some underlying data is always numeric?   The opposite would be okay where the underlying data is text but can be accessed somehow as numeric when needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate the value in your viewmodel from the value displayed, you can use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

For example, you can have a viewmodel like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.myValue = ko.observable(0);
    this.displayedValue = ko.computed({
        read: return self.myValue().toFixed(8),
        write: function (value) { 
            self.myValue(value); //maybe do something to ensure you save a number
        } 
    });
}
```

When you need to do a calculation, use `myValue`, but use `displayedValue` for your html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right" 
       data-bind="value: displayedValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the value is being updated from underneath the user is because you are using `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`. This will be a problem for anything that will change the text, as it will confuse the user if the text changes as they type. If you don't use `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` then the text can be changed when they tab out of the field. The extenders work fine for that case.